# What is maximum size about mysql to running Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, web-traffic

I have one WordPress site using MySQL for the database, normally each post is attached with a lot of photos and daily traffic is about 5,000-8,000. My current Database size is 750MB and wp-content/uploads = 2.75GB

My question is in the future if my website grows to have 10,000 posts, will it be possible to be running? (in case of the disk space is enough) or will my site be very slow?

Thank you

Comment: wordpress.com has several million posts and it runs just fine. It's a question of hardware, not software.

Comment: I mean Wordpress run on my own hosting

Comment: It will depend on your hosting. If you have hosted on a powerful dedicated server then there will be no problem. Since you can scale it.

Comment: Yes, I understood the question. If wordpress.com runs millions of posts without problems, why would your own hosting have problems with a tiny fraction of that? It's the exact same software.

Comment: Thank you @NadunKulatunge now i using Digitalocean and scale up function is enable , just to make sure in the future if a lot of data not slow down like query or pageload.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help =) @droidstack